# Is there a C# sdk/wrapper for Azure Resource Management API calls?

Tags: c#, api, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

I want to execute resource group based calls. For example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163572.aspx

Azure Management Libraries don't seem to have this capability (unless I'm missing something). Is there any SDK or client wrapper available that can make that kind of call?

EDIT:
Gaurav pointed me at exactly what I needed. Going to do people a solid and expand upon what I did to help clear the muddy muddy waters that is the Azure Resource Management API.

In your app's Packet Manager do:
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources -Pre
Then
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute -Pre
Then
Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory -Pre

Follow this blog for getting an authorization header/token:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722415.aspx

Then call the new API like so (note the slight name changes):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var token = GetAuthorizationHeader();
        var credential = new Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials(token);
        using (var client = new ComputeManagementClient(credential) { SubscriptionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["subscriptionId"] })
        {
            var vms = client.VirtualMachines.ListAll();
        }
    }

    private static string GetAuthorizationHeader()
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = null;

        var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"]);

        string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"];
        string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"];
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            result = context.AcquireToken(
              "https://management.core.windows.net/",
              clientCred);
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Name = "AquireTokenThread";
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        string token = result.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I've always rolled my own, once you have a service principle created there are perhaps ten lines of code to execute that and get a response. Does the .net sdk not have that functionality?

Comment: It does. I'm using the System WebRequest to make my calls right now. It works but sdk's have explicitly defined objects for request and response making developing much quicker and cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the package you're looking for is [`Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources 3.4.0-preview`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources/3.4.0-preview). You can find the complete source code for Azure Resource Manager here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/src/ResourceManagement.

Comment: You helped me with azure once again! Thanks Gaurav.